Identifier les tags qu'un utilisateur particulier a introduits dans le système
Existe-t-il un moyen de trouver la liste des tags qu'un utilisateur a formulés lui/elle-même ?
(Je sais que j'ai introduit plusieurs tags et je suis curieux de savoir lesquels, ou  de connaitre la liste de ceux qui ont survécu. (La liste de ceux qui ont été rejetés m'intéresse aussi.)

Hmm, je pense que non. En lisant le API je trouve des moyens de voir quels sont les tags que favorise un utilisateur donné (activité, questions créées, réponses écrites), mais les données sur le tag lui-même semblent être très limitées.

@LukeSawczak Alors ce n'est probablement pas possible ; merci d'avoir fait cette recherche.

The only source that can give you certainty about who created a certain tag is the list of people who got the taxonomist badge. However, this badge is only awarded if the tag has been used by at least 50 questions, so it does not cover all tags.
